# Create Single Sites-available conf for multiple url with same domain and folder path using SSL

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I want to have two sites that use the same domain name and also shares same folder and what separates them is a prefix in the URL.

For example:

1. mywebsite.domain.com  => /var/www/site1
2. mywebsite1.domain.com => /var/www/site1

How can I achieve this in apache2 on port 443? i just want to configure it in 000-default.conf file instead of creating multipe sites.conf file.

Comment: Use `ServerAlias` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i have added ServerAlias but not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a catch all, you configure a _default that is used for any of your subdomains, if you have one certificate that covers both domains through a SAN subject alternative name or a wildcard certificate this will work.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

But if you have two separate certificates, you need two configuration VirtualHost blocks, they can be in the same file

```
<VirtualHost mywebsite.domain.com:443>
   <bla></bla>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost mywebsite1.domain.com:443>
   <bla></bla>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, i have checked my certificate is wildcard certificate and also tried your way you suggested but it doesn't worked.

Comment: check the error log file for clues why it doesn't work. 
tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Yes it shows "server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name"

Comment: I have added **ip address in server name** so now i have changed it to **domain.com** but now error gone but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a catch all, you configure a _default that is used for any of your subdomains, if you have one certificate that covers both domains through a SAN subject alternative name or a wildcard certificate this will work.